# Multiple instances of Random.nextBoolean giving the same value;

Tags: java

So I need to have 3 instances of coin run in A1, and simulate a coin flip independently, but every time they run they all return the same value. I'm not sure what the problem is so I'll just link all of my code.

```
public class A1main {
public static Coin nickel = new Coin();
public static Coin dime = new Coin();
public static Coin quarter = new Coin();
public static double balance = 0.00;

public static void main(String[]args){
tossall();
checkAndAdd();
System.out.print(balance);
}
public static void tossall(){
    nickel.toss();
    dime.toss();
    quarter.toss();
    System.out.print(nickel.getSideUp()+ dime.getSideUp() + quarter.getSideUp());
}
public static void checkAndAdd(){
    if(nickel.getSideUp().equals("heads")){
        balance += .05;
}
    if(dime.getSideUp().equals("heads")){
        balance += .10;
}
    if(quarter.getSideUp().equals("heads")){
        balance += .25;
}
}
}

package A1;
import java.util.*;

public class Coin {
    public static Random rand = new Random();
    public static String sideUp; //Can this be static?
   public Coin(){
boolean side = rand.nextBoolean(); //used to store/determine side up Heads == true Tails == false.
if(side){
    sideUp = "heads";
}else{
    sideUp = "tails";
}
}
public static void toss(){
    boolean side = rand.nextBoolean(); //used to store/determine side up Heads == true Tails == false.
    if(side){
        sideUp = "heads";
    }else{
        sideUp = "tails";
    }
}
public static String getSideUp(){
    return sideUp;
}
}
```

Comment: No, that cannot be static.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class

Comment: If I make the string non static it can't be used by toss() and getSideUp(), what do I need to do in order to get the whole thing to work?

Comment: They shouldn't be static either.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out, I don't know if this thread is hidden now, but in case anyone has a similar problem I was trying to access a non static variable in static methods, so I just made the methods non static and everything worked. Edit: Thanks for the help everyone.